# How to generate pandas datafarmes from an array of appended dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data where I calculate total annual revenue by country by fruit. The dataframe cuts are placed into a list called 'final_df_list':

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import rec, nan

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_records(rec.array([(202001, 2020, 'apples', 'CA', 100),
         (202002, 2020, 'apples', 'CA', 150),
         (202001, 2020, 'apples', 'USA', 400),
         (202002, 2020, 'apples', 'USA', 675),
         (202001, 2020, 'oranges', 'CA', 50),
         (202002, 2020, 'oranges', 'CA', 65),
         (202001, 2020, 'oranges', 'USA', 175),
         (202002, 2020, 'oranges', 'USA', 390)], 
                  dtype=[('yyyymm', '<i8'), ('year', '<i8'), ('prod', 'O'), ('country', 'O'), ('rev', '<i8')]))

final_df_list = list()
for col in df1.country.unique():
    final_df_list.append(df1.where(df1.country == col).groupby(['year', 'prod','country']).sum()[["rev"]])
```

The results look like this:

[image]

I have 2 separate questions...how do I:

1. Break out these dataframes by country as 2 traditional pandas dataframe (i.e. look like excel tables) called df1_rev_CA, df1_rev_USA?
2. View these 2 dataframes as a single pandas dataframe (called df2_rev)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final_df_list = list()
final_dict = {}
for col in df1.country.unique():
    final_df_list.append(df1.where(df1.country == col).groupby(['year', 'prod','country']).sum()[["rev"]])
    
    # question 1:
    
    # option 1, create dataframe variables (generally considered bad practice)
    globals()["df1_rev_"+col] = df1.where(df1.country == col).groupby(['year', 'prod','country']).sum()[["rev"]]
    # option 2, append to dictionary.  Then you can call this by `final_dict["df1_rev_USD"]`
    final_dict["df1_rev_"+col] = df1.where(df1.country == col).groupby(['year', 'prod','country']).sum()[["rev"]]
    
# question 2:

pd.concat(final_df_list)
#                           rev
#year   prod    country        
#2020.0 apples  CA        250.0
#       oranges CA        115.0
#       apples  USA      1075.0
#       oranges USA       565.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `pivot_table`

`pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ['year', 'prod','country'], values='rev', aggfunc=np.sum)`

returns

```
                       rev
year prod    country
2020 apples  CA        250
             USA      1075
     oranges CA        115
             USA       565
```

And instead of complicating it with lists, you could just use `unstack` to convert from tall to wide:

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ['year', 'prod','country'], values='rev', aggfunc=np.sum).unstack()
              rev
country        CA   USA
year prod
2020 apples   250  1075
     oranges  115   565
>>>
```

Now you can access directly to each of them as a normal multi-index dataframe:

```
>>> ddf[('rev','CA')]
year  prod
2020  apples     250
      oranges    115
Name: (rev, CA), dtype: int64
>>>
```